# Eloquent: hook into 'saving' event on both the model and his parent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Having this parent:

```php
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    protected static $rules = [];

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model) {
            return $model->validate(); // <- this executes
        });
    }
}
```

How can I be able to still do the same on the child model?

```php
class Car extends BaseModel {
    protected static $rules = [];

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model) {
            $model->doStuff(); // <- this doesn't execute
        });
    }
}
```

The `saving()` in the child only executes if I remove the `saving()` on the parent. I need both!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out the solution and it's actually pretty simple.

Here is the behavior of the `*ing` Eloquent events, depending on the return type:

- `return null` or `no return`: the model will be saved or the next `saving` callback will be executed
- `return true`: the model will be saved but the next `saving` callback will **NOT** be executed
- `return false`: the model will not be saved and the next `saving` callback will not be executed

So, the solution for this problem will be simply:

```php
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    protected static $rules = [];

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model) {
            if(!$model->validate())
                return false; // only return false if validate() fails, otherwise don't return anything
        });
    }
}
```